# Custom PC Linux issues

Tags: linux, installation, motherboard, bios, freeze

I have built myself a custom PC desktop and I am trying to install any flavor of Linux but there is always a hang issue that i cannot seem to get around. I currently have Windows 7 installed and the process went without a hitch. Now that I try to install linux from a CD or USB i always get frozen right after an AHCI message. Below will be my specs and my bios setup. Hopefully somebody can point me in the right direction to get linux up and running.

**Specs**
Intel I5 4670k (Haswell),
8Gb corsair vengeance RAM,
NVIDIA EVGA gtx 760 4gb,
Gigabyte UD5 z97 motherboard.

Picutures will be attached below, I have searched alot for a solution to this issue but to no avail, any help would be appreciated.

[image: Bios Features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJaF1l.jpg)]

[image: Peripherals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKCTNl.jpg)]

Comment: reputation would not allow me to post full links. So i attached the important ones

Comment: All sata configurations are set to IDE mode. Linux message before hang reads: "ahci 0000:07:00.0: flags: 64bit ncq sntf led only pmp fbs pio slu part sxs" after that message the system freezes

Comment: Switching all SATA configs to AHCI does not help either

Comment: Which flavor or flavors of Linux have you tried to install? Also, cropping and resizing your pictures (remove extraneous parts and reduce to a reasonable resolution before posting) would be helpful in future.

Comment: What are the SATA settings on the second picture?

Comment: What Linux installations are you using?  Are you using grub?  What happens if you pass "noapic" and "noalpic" parameters to the kernel?

Comment: I've tried Ubuntu, Kali , and ParrotOS all hang at the same part. Using GNU Grub and passing noapic and noalpic through kernel does not change the boot for me . All Sata options are currently set to IDE, when switched to ahci it still poses same issue. I have tried using the IGFX

Comment: on the second picture, could you post what it shows under the SATA Configuration? or upload it to imgur or something